# Turning off auto-exposure compensation completely?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm writing a camera application that requires the same exposure regardless of ambient light.  Unfortunately, setExposureCompensation() only acts like an offset.  Can I turn off this auto adjustment, or is this more of a pre-user hardware correction?

Comment: As old as this is, you've probably moved past this, but I've updated my answer below to reference a new 4.0+ API for exposure locking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: So, for Android 4.0 and above, there is a [`setAutoExposureLock(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setAutoExposureLock%28boolean%29) that should work for what you need. It doesn't let you set the exposure yourself, but after the exposure is determined, you can lock it into its current exposure. You need to guard it with a check for `isAutoExposureLockSupported()`, though, to make sure the device supports that feature.

To get the same actual exposure every time, you'd need to be able to set a fixed ISO, shutter speed, and aperture. As you said, the exposure compensation only offsets from the metered exposure, which the camera determines automatically. To my knowledge, there's no built in way to set the ISO, the shutter speed, or the aperture values in Android.

Comment: I know this post is very old, however, I have been looking for the solution to set exposure value. It looks like it's feasible to set the exposure value. Just look at any camera app in the store and it allows you set the exposure value.

Comment: @pree Did you check the docs? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation(int)

Comment: Oh yes, of course. It only mentions setExposureCompensation() etc APIs as mentioned above as well. However, I'm curious to know how other camera apps (standard one and google play market) are able to set exposure values. I also posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620850/android-camera-settings-change-exposure-programatically

Comment: This is no longer the case with the release of Camera2 with Android Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

You should browse all your camera parameters to see if there are any related to ISO,shutter speed, and aperture.

Example:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
String sParams = params.flatten();
Log.d("TAG", "camera flatten: "+sParams);
```