# Disable camera brightness auto adjustment

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning off auto-exposure compensation completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620585/turning-off-auto-exposure-compensation-completely)

I realize, under normal room light condition, my camera is able to achieve 14~15 FPS.

```
mCamera2.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // FPS being recorded. No further processing is done.
    }
});
```

However, when I cover the camera with a black object, or the entire FPS will drop to 8~9 FPS. I suspect the camera is trying to auto increase its exposure time, so that its CCD may receive more light under low light condition.

However, I prefer not to have such unstable FPS in my application. I prefer to disable such "auto brightness adjustment" feature, so that I can have a more or less consistent FPS.

May I know how I can disable camera auto brightness adjustment feature?