# What is this Android Camera setting called and how can I set it?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm trying to integrate a Camera into my application.

I notice that when I point the camera at a bright object, the image is made darker. For example, if I point the camera at a bright LCD monitor, the image adjusts to make the monitor readable, and as a consequence makes everything else in the image very dark.

I'm curious what this is called and if there is a way I can disable it/manually control it in an application.

This behaviour can be observed in the stock camera app as well. None of the settings seem to change this behaviour in the stock app (although turning on HDR obviously tends to reduce the darkening of the surrounding areas).

Comment: Auto white balancing.

Answer (score 1):

It's called auto white balancing, and you will probably need to use the [Camera.Parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) to change it....

Comment: I thought that was the case, but the stock app lets you change the white balance; the icons clearly correspond to the Camera.Parameter settings WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO, WHITE_BALANCE_CLOUDY_DAYLIGHT etc. Selecting a different value in the stock app doesn't change this behavior, and setting these parameters on a Camera object doesn't either. It seems to just make the image a little more yellow, little more blue, etc. - Unless I'm missing something, of course.

Comment: did you try to `setWhiteBalance("WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO"); setParameters(newParams);` ? Also, did you try to turn off the auto white balance lock (AWB) ?

Comment: Yes, I set the new parameters on the camera object.

Comment: Try messing around with exposure as well then :)

Comment: Also, did you `stopPreview(); startPreview();` after changing parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

I've determined that it's called auto exposure compensation, and there's no way to control it.

[Turning off auto-exposure compensation completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620585/turning-off-auto-exposure-compensation-completely)

You can set exposure compensation, but this is basically an offset to what the camera determines. You can also lock the exposure level. But you can't set the full range of exposure values manually.