# android camera settings - change exposure programatically

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm writing an android app which just displays camera preview. I also change some camera settings like exposure as below:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setExposureCompensation(params.getMaxExposureCompensation()); // maximum
mCamera.setParameters(params);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

However, when I start the standard camera app and set the exposure to maximum (2), it's much brighter than my preview. Any idea why my app's preview is not as bright as the standard camera's preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code was actually working fine.

I tried looking into some open source camera apps and found out that they were also increasing the brightness along with the exposure.