# Disable automatic adjustments of android camera

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I'm trying to subtract background of videostream by making `cv::absdiff`:

```
absdiff(rgbvs[i], bgs[i], diffs[i]);
```

The problem is that android camera makes automatic adjustments of brightness, exposure or something else, so there are huge artifacts even with small brightness changes:
[image: bg image]
[image: image with light object (brightness of scene changed)]

I'm using default android camera api:`import android.hardware.Camera;` and `onPreviewFrame` for processing.
I've tried next things to prevent automatic adjustments, but they had no effect - brightness still changes depending on scene:

```
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.set("whitebalance", "shade");
            parameters.set("iso", "ISO800");
            parameters.set("auto-exposure", "frame-average");
            parameters.set("brightness-step", "0");
            parameters.set("lensshade", "disable");

            if(parameters.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
                parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
            }
            if(parameters.isAutoWhiteBalanceLockSupported()) {
                parameters.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
            }

            parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: Check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620790/7041015
Hope it helps.